# How to properly create table from MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table called "schedule" for the NFL schedule where there is a gameid, homeid, awayid,  weekno and seasonno.  For each team's BYE week, there is a 0 in the awayid and their id is in the homeid.

NOTE:  All bye weeks happen between week 4 and week 11.

So I want to simply get the team's city and BYE week in a MYSQL query joining with my "teams" table (teamid, location) so I can display it in a table.

I tried this...

```
$sql = "SELECT *,
    h.location AS home,
    a.location AS away,
    h.teamid AS homeid,
    a.teamid AS awayid,
    s.weekno
FROM schedule s
    INNER JOIN teams h ON s.homeid = h.teamid 
    LEFT JOIN teams a ON s.awayid = a.teamid 
WHERE s.seasonno = $currentyear
AND s.awayid=0
ORDER BY weekno ASC";

$schedule= mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (!$schedule) {
die("Database query failed: " . mysqli_error($connection));
} else { 
// Placeholder for data
    $data = array();
    $number=1;
    // Loop through results
    $i=4;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($schedule)) {

            while($row['weekno']==$i) {
            ${'tabledata'.$i}.=$row['home'];

            }
            $i++;

    }
}
```

but I just get the FIRST team for each bye week, not ALL teams.  For example, week 4 should be Tennesse AND New England.

```
4   Tennessee
5   Miami
6   Tampa Bay
7   Chicago
8   Jacksonville
9   Houston
10  San Francisco
11  Cleveland
```

This is the display code...

```
<table>
<tr><th>Week #</th><th>Teams</th></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td><?php echo $tabledata4;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td><?php echo $tabledata5;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>6</td><td><?php echo $tabledata6;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td><?php echo $tabledata7;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td><?php echo $tabledata8;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td><?php echo $tabledata9;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>10</td><td><?php echo $tabledata10;?></td><tr>
<tr><td>11</td><td><?php echo $tabledata11;?></td><tr>
</table>
```

It already looks way too convoluted for what should probably be an easy query/display.  For instance, I'm not even sure I need to do the INNER JOIN but too confused to know for sure.

Can someone get me on right course to stave off further convolution?

Comment: If you execute the quary directly on the database, do you get the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner `while` loop is creating the problem I think. (It is actually a wonder it shows anything at all)

```
while($row['weekno']==$i) {
    ${'tabledata'.$i}.=$row['home'];
}
$i++;
```

Change that to

```
$i = $row['weekno'] 
${'tabledata'.$i}.=$row['home'];
```

And it should work.

Comment: Sorry to throw you off, but when it DID show stuff I actually had the "$i++" INSIDE the smaller while loop.  SO you were totally right it shouldn't have shown anything the way I copy and pasted the code into the question.  Anyway, you were dead on correct, your code does exactly what I want. Thank you so much!